# MDX: IIf condition on the value of a dimension is always false

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, ssas-2008, iif

I am trying to produce a different output in a column dependent on whether the value of a dimension `[Scenario].[Option]` is `+5` which I've tried to achieve using the `IIf` function.

```
WITH MEMBER [XorY] AS
(
    IIf([Scenario].[Option] = +5, 'X', 'Y')
    --IIf([Scenario].[Option].&[+5], 'X', 'Y')
)
SELECT
NON EMPTY
(
    [Scenario].[Option].[Option]
) ON ROWS,
NON EMPTY
(
    [XorY]
) ON COLUMNS
FROM [RePro]
WHERE
(
    [ABC].[ABC].[Val]
) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE
```

However, using either of the `IIf` statements as above, `[XorY]` is always `Y` regardless of the value of `[Scenario].[Option]`. It seems the comparison I'm doing is just syntactically wrong or something. How do I do this? I've noticed it works much better if I use a calculated member in a `[Measures]` dimension in the `IIf` condition, but that is not possible in my case - I must use `[Scenario].[Option]`.

Thanks for any help received :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use a member statement, you generally want to use currentmember, as it references the current cell. Combine that with membervalue and you get the value. In this case I then wrapped the expected answer in quotes.

```
WITH MEMBER [XorY] AS
(
   IIf([Scenario].[Option].currentMember.membervalue = "+5", 'X', 'Y')
)
```

If you are comparing to a number you would do:

```
WITH MEMBER [XorY] AS
(
   IIf(STRTOVALUE([Scenario].[Option].currentMember.membervalue) = 5, 'X', 'Y')
)
```

This can return an error if not all of the members in [Scenario].[Option] are numbers. There is also a potential performance issue with the conversion.

Comment: Thanks! I actually found this answer in Deepak Puri's answer here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d6e4eb06-aba4-4aa1-9c28-65f264464832
The TechNet on `IIf` (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145994.aspx) only covers `[Measures]` dimensions, not non-`[Measures]` dimensions. I'm sure this is noddy stuff, but it's taken me all day to resolve this. Interestingly, using just `MemberValue` instead of `CurrentMember.MemberValue` works as well - not sure what the difference is, though.